# How to concatenate two fields in v-select's item-text vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Using vue2.6, vuetify 2.3, I have a v-select menu with a list of module names and for the item-text I want to change from displaying a single value to a value with 2 field combined together connecting with a hyphen.

Currently, I have the item-text to display the module name only which I got from my database.

```
<v-select
   :items="deplist"
   item-text="moduleName"
   item-value="moduleId"
   v-model="selection"
></v-select>
```

I want to change the item-text component by concacentating 2 fields (moduleName,moduleNum) with a hyphen in between. How can I do that inside item-text?

```
item-text="moduleName" + "-" + "moduleNum"
ex: "Mathematics-108"
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a shorthand function to return the concatenated values...

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
  :item-text="item=>`${item.moduleName} - ${item.moduleNum}`"
  item-value="moduleId"
  v-model="selection"
>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/XE4L6qNATD)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a different value directly inside the slot available.

```
<v-select
   :items="deplist"
   item-value="moduleId"
   v-model="selection"
>
 <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
  {{ `${item.moduleName} - ${item.moduleNum}` }}
 </template>

</v-select>
```

With this slot `selection`, when you select a value, this will display the html inside the slot.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write like following.
Please revert, if it works or not?

```
item-text="moduleName+'-'+moduleNum"
```